# 7-bits up to 0xEF

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

While researching Unicode issues in Python3, I can across this [often-quoted document](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html) which lays out the initial ideas behind Python3 Unicode support. A quote from that page:

> For historical reasons, the most widely used encoding is ascii, which can only handle Unicode code points in the range 0-0xEF (i.e. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding).

I understand that `0xEF` = `14*16 + 15*1 = 239`. This seems wrong to me, as binary `1111111` (7 bits) is `127`. Is this quote wrong, or is my understanding wrong?

**UPDATE:** The document has been fixed! Thanks to Nick Coghlan for his excellent introduction to Python 3 string handling, and to bobince for his help in confirming the typo.

Comment: What does `0xEF` represent?

Comment: This is indeed strange, since 7-bit ASCII has range `00` to `7F`, and `0xEF` is clearly 8-bit. And the paragraph does not refer to UTF-8 either. File a bug!

Comment: Thanks, I simply left a comment on that page's comment feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `0xEF` appears to be a simple typo. The section makes perfect sense with that replaced by `0x7F`.